# pytest cannot find database and tables

Tags: python-3.x, django, pytest-django, pytest-xdist

I am trying to speed up the test runtime by using `pytest-xdist`, previously I was using pytest, pytest-django to run the tests,

After installing `pytest-xdist`, One is an issue which I am facing is most of the tests are failing with messages that relation does not exist

`pytest -n auto accounts/tests`

for example
 `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "auth_user" does not exist`

I guess there is error which says database does not exist:
 `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "test_dev" does not exist`

But the interesting thing is some of tests are passing :(

Comment: are you creating the tables from outside migrations? otherwise this probably shouldn't happen.

Comment: No, thre are no tables outside migrations

Comment: Have you solved the issue?